# Pointer to fixed size array indexing

Tags: c, opencl

Consider the following code:

```
typedef float image_buffer[1024][1024];

void f(image_buffer *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = 0; // doesn't work
            (*b)[i][j] = 0; // also doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

People are complaining that there is no question, but the question is obvious, how do you index fixed size array having a pointer to it...?
Thank you!

EDIT: OpenCL code:

```
typedef float image_buffer[1024][1024];
__kernel void kernel1(sampler_t smp, read_only image2d_t a, read_only image2d_t b, __global image_buffer *r)
{
    __local float shared[16][16];

    float4 colorA = read_imagef(a, smp, (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1))),
           colorB = read_imagef(b, smp, (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1)));

    (*r)[get_global_id(0)][get_global_id(1)] = (colorA.x - colorB.x) * (colorA.x - colorB.x) + (colorA.y - colorB.y) * (colorA.y - colorB.y) + (colorA.z - colorB.z) * (colorA.z - colorB.z) + (colorA.w - colorB.w) * (colorA.w - colorB.w);
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: `(*b)[i][j] = 0;` Works for me

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a description of the problem. You need to tell us what is supposed to happen and what actually happens (compiler error, segmentation fault, your computer explodes, you know, **describe** it).

Comment: A runtime error occurs InvalidCommandQueue if it tells you something, haven't thought that it would be useful to provide the code because it is OpenCL code which is C99 dialect, now I think that the problem not with C but rather OpenCL, now I've provided the code, in EDIT section

Comment: I have to admit that it is my blunder, I've supplied 256 bytes instead 1 megabyte of memory thats why it was crashing... It seems that I've overworked.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
typedef float** image_buffer;
```

In any case, the correct syntax would be:

```
(*b)[i][j] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
typedef float image_buffer[1024][1024];

void f(image_buffer *b)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
            {
            (*b)[i][j] = 0; // this works on gcc -std=c99 $FILE
            }
        }
    }
```

No `main`, so linker error, but it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are making an invalid assertion that something "doesn't work", while in reality it works perfectly fine. Which is why people might complain that there's no actual question in your "question".

The proper way to access you array inside the function is

```
void f(image_buffer *b)
{
  ...
  (*b)[i][j] = 0;
  ...
}
```

And yes, it works. If it "doesn't work" for you, you have to explain what you mean exactly. "Doesn't work" is not really a meaningful explanation.